# Devise: Place a variable in the confirmation email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, devise

I am trying to customise the confirmation email in order to pass an extra variable than the resource and confirmation token.

In particular what I want is to get the existing (soon to be overridden) email of the user passed into the confirmation email so that when the user clicks on the confirmation link, the page he goes to will have the user's old email in the parameters.

I'm not sure where I will need to make this change exactly (maybe mailer view or devise mailer?) and also what is the best way to override this in my rails app without touching the devise gem at all?

Or maybe there is even a better way I can get the user's old email after he confirms on the link but, as far as I'm aware, once that happens the old email is gone for good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `rails generate devise:views`.

This will generate all the views that Devise uses internally so you can make your modifications.

**NOTE**

This will generate `erb` templates. If you wish to use `haml` or anything else. [Here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Create-Haml-and-Slim-Views) is a tutorial on how you can go about this process.

Comment: Ah got it. I put resource.email and resource.unconfirmed_email in the devise view of the confirmation mail and it shows both emails so that works great for me thanks!